# When I call TestNG.run() through a method in struts2 class, the tests run but reportNG and the index.html are not updated

Tags: struts2, testng, reportng

I created a simple struts application, according  the user input it calls the action method and in turn it calls testNG.run ()

The tests are executed just fine but the reports are not updated with the new result neither the reportNG.

The same methods when through main method the reports are generated just fine.
Any suggestions why this is happening or how to achieve this scenario?

---

More Details: 
1. I am using TestNG, ReportNG, and struts actions to take user inputs. 
2. using struts I created a jsp with form action: executeTest1 
3. when submitted/clicked it calls a method in the action class. 
4. In action class that extends ActionSupport,

```
public String addMemo() {
            TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();            
            TestNG testng = new TestNG();
            List<String> suites = Lists.newArrayList();
            suites.add("path-to-Suite1.xml");
            testng.setTestSuites(suites);
            testng.addListener(tla);
            testng.run();
            System.out.println(" -- Done.");

        return SUCCESS;     
    }
```

5. the tests run successfully, but the reportNG is not generated, neithere the testNG reports.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I updated the description. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you calling tests from the action?

Comment: Cause I don't want run the .xml from eclipse, I want other users to choose which test cases to run. If u have other suggestions please advise.